# Finding work as a paraplegic ( Wheelchair bound, paralysed)

Tags: student, disability

I am 39 years old and was involved in a car accident 3 years ago. I was in the construction industry all my life. After the accident, I can no longer work in this field and decided to study BCompt accounting.

What steps can I take to ensure that I will be accepted in the corporate world?

What resources are available to help me build a career as an accountant?

Comment: Even something like a risk assessor for the building industry - you have lots of relevant experience...

Comment: @Pudora I edited this, check now.

Comment: I tell you now, if this gets closed, I will be voting to re-open.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest that you specialize in any form of accounting that specializes in building and construction, as that is your background.  The book ["What color is your parachute"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/198485657X) Can help you find a way to combine your talents and interests with your new chosen career.

I would also get in touch with your county's "Vocational rehab" office, and see how they can help you.  Often, Vocational rehabilitation offices have partnerships with various disabilities advocates groups which in tern have corporate connections and assistance in job placement.  Businesses get tax breaks for hiring people with disabilities, and that can help you get in the door.  Again, talk to Vocational Rehabilitation about that as well.

Get involved in the disabilities advocates groups, as they may be able to help you.  Just be careful to get involved in the ones that are more involved with assistance.  Some are little more than lobbying groups, and they can't help you get back to work, as that is not their focus.

There are plenty of other resources out there, but Vocational Rehabilitation, and Disabilities groups are the best places to start.  The stigma against people with disabilities is much much less than it used to be, so don't get discouraged

GOOD LUCK!